# Detrending a TimeSeries

Tags: time-series

I am trying to de-trend a time series that I know has some seasonality.  So I thought I would try to use TimeSeries and DateObject functionality to do it.  Here's what I have so far :

```
input = {{"Date", 
"Count"}, {DateObject[{2009, 8, 24}, 
 TimeObject[{0, 0, 0.`}, TimeZone -> 0.`], TimeZone -> 0.`], 
327.29`}, {DateObject[{2009, 8, 25}, 
 TimeObject[{0, 0, 0.`}, TimeZone -> 0.`], TimeZone -> 0.`], 
347.6`}, {DateObject[{2009, 8, 26}, 
 TimeObject[{0, 0, 0.`}, TimeZone -> 0.`], TimeZone -> 0.`], 
294.`}, {DateObject[{2009, 8, 27}, 
 TimeObject[{0, 0, 0.`}, TimeZone -> 0.`], TimeZone -> 0.`], 
311.`}, {DateObject[{2009, 8, 28}, 
 TimeObject[{0, 0, 0.`}, TimeZone -> 0.`], TimeZone -> 0.`], 
786.`}, {DateObject[{2009, 8, 29}, 
 TimeObject[{0, 0, 0.`}, TimeZone -> 0.`], TimeZone -> 0.`], 
867.`}, {DateObject[{2009, 8, 30}, 
 TimeObject[{0, 0, 0.`}, TimeZone -> 0.`], TimeZone -> 0.`], 
760.`}, {DateObject[{2009, 8, 31}, 
 TimeObject[{0, 0, 0.`}, TimeZone -> 0.`], TimeZone -> 0.`], 
643.`}, {DateObject[{2009, 9, 1}, 
 TimeObject[{0, 0, 0.`}, TimeZone -> 0.`], TimeZone -> 0.`], 
435.`}, {DateObject[{2009, 9, 2}, 
 TimeObject[{0, 0, 0.`}, TimeZone -> 0.`], TimeZone -> 0.`], 
456.`}, {DateObject[{2009, 9, 3}, 
 TimeObject[{0, 0, 0.`}, TimeZone -> 0.`], TimeZone -> 0.`], 
235.`}, {DateObject[{2009, 9, 4}, 
 TimeObject[{0, 0, 0.`}, TimeZone -> 0.`], TimeZone -> 0.`], 
346.`}};

assoc = AssociationThread[First[input] -> #] & /@ Rest[input];
v = Flatten[Values[assoc[[All, {"Count"}]]]];
t = Flatten[Values[assoc[[All, {"Date"}]]]];
ts = TimeSeries[v, {t}];
tsmodel = TimeSeriesModelFit[ts]
fitmodel = Fit[ts, {1, x, x^2}, x]
```

Questions

1. Is the Flatten really the best way to go from an association to a
   TS?  I tried a number of ways but that was the only one that worked.
2. How do I subtract the fitted model(s) from the Time series?  I have
   tried the technique [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/applications/timeseries/UsersGuideToTimeSeries/PreparingDataForModeling/1.4.3.html) but no luck.

Comment: An answer to your first question: you can try using `TimeSeries` directly, e.g. `DateListPlot@TimeSeries[Rest@input]` .

Comment: An answer to your second question. Does the following command do what you want? `DateListPlot[{TimeSeries[Rest@input] - 
   TimeSeries[tsmodel /@ input[[2 ;; -1, 1]], {input[[2 ;; -1, 1]]}]}`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. `TimeSeries[Rest[input]]` works directly without having to go through an association.
2. If you really need to make an association: `assoc = Inner[#2 -> #1 &, Rest[input], First[input], Association]`. From there: `TimeSeries[Values[assoc]]`.
3. `TimeSeriesMapThread[]` is useful for detrending:

   ```
   ts = TimeSeries[Rest[input]];
   trend = LinearModelFit[ts, {1, x, x^2}, x];
   dts = TimeSeriesMapThread[#2 - trend[#1] &, ts];
   {DateListPlot[ts, PlotLabel -> "Original"], 
    DateListPlot[dts, PlotLabel -> "Detrended"]} // GraphicsRow
   ```

   [image: before and after]

Comment: Lovely answer - I'm a database person at heart so my inclination is always to create query-able tabular structures like assoc's and DS's